# How to break the program after my time completed in python?

Tags: python, time

I have a program to stop the for loop, even though the loop is running. I want to exit from this loop once my timer is over.

Ex: Timer set to = 10 seconds

```
def Start_function():
    timer = 10 seconds
    for i in range(60):
      print(i)
      time.sleep(1)
    return
```

Here loop will continue executing till for loop completion. But I need to exit from this function once the time is reached 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add an if condition to check `if i == timer:` and then `return` to terminate the program.

```
import time
def Start_function():
    timer = 10
    for i in range(60):
        if i == timer:
            return "Timer ran successfully"
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
'Timer ran successfully'
```

But this is a bad implementation of a timer. You can improve by:

```
def Start_function(timer):
    for i in range(timer):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)

Start_function(10) # This starts the timer for 10 second
```